# Laravel Accessor on Pascal Case Attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am getting data from an external db which uses PascalCase for column names eg: `ClientStatus`,
I did write an accessor, but due to casing issue its not working.

```
    public function getClientStatusAttribute() {
        return $this->attributes['ClientStatus']."modified value";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either access it using `ClientModel->client_status` or override HasAttribute trait's two methods `hasGetMutator()` and `mutateAttribute()` 
Laravel Model uses HasAttribute trait.
Model uses HasAttribute trait's two methods `hasGetMutator()` and `mutateAttribute()` to check if accessor exits or not and if exsits then return its value. 
`hasGetMutator()` which by default uses `studly` helper method to make `snake_case` attribute to `PascalCase`
That's why we create accessor `get{AttributeName}Attribute` in this manner.So,make these methods something link this

```
public function hasGetMutator($key)
{
  return method_exists($this, 'get'.$key.'Attribute');
}

protected function mutateAttribute($key, $value)
{
  return $this->{'get'.$key.'Attribute'}($value);
}
```

Above we removed studly helper method, so when we try access a `PascalCase` attribute, first it will check if accessor exists, if yes then return its value.